# Storing structured Maven derived information in a Database

Tags: database, maven, build, regression

Are there any utilities for storing maven information into a database?  In particular, I'd like to store performance data from my maven - failsafe integration tests - which also serve as performance tests -  (i.e. how long each test took to run), so that after every run, I can plot performance improvements in my builds over time.

I'm assuming that there might be a general purpose plugin/took for archiving maven target/surefire and target/failsafe info which can be easily queried , and that I can use that as a starting point for building some persistent build information into my builds. Once that persistance is there, a simple script could extract and generate performance regression or other statistics which depend on analyzing the outputs of multiple independent builds over time.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/) (previously called Sonar). One of the [standard metrics](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Metric+definitions) captured is unit test duration. If you're using Bamboo or Jenkins there is an additional [build stability plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Build+Stability+Plugin) which captures metrics related to build duration, success and failures.

Comment: Is sonarqube used in a modular lowerlevel sort of way?  or is it structured as a monolithic app.

Comment: Like Jenkins it's a standalone app. Its function is to store your stats in a database and present a project dashboard. Try it out, very easy to setup.